# Stop keypress popup inside input fields

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to create a search modal, when user press <kbd>s</kbd>, it will run a search box. It works, but two problems:

1. When modal is loaded, if user press <kbd>s</kbd> again, it will override and load again the modal box.
2. Modal shouldn't be loaded within textarea or input fields when pressing <kbd>S</kbd>.

```js
$("body").bind('keyup', function(event) { 
    if (event.which == 83) {
        $('#search-modal').show();
    }
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I see from a comment that you might have changed your approach in your application, but for it's academic value - to answer the question as written:

You can use `.on()` instead of `.bind()` *(which has been deprecated as of jQuery 1.7)* and `.off()` to add/remove event handlers.

This will permit you to turn that event handler on/off as desired.

```js
$("body").on('keyup', function(event) {
  if (event.which == 83) {
    $('#mdl').show();
    $('body').off('keyup'); //the "s" will only work once
  }
});
$('#mdl_closeX').click(function(){
  $('#mdl').hide();
});
```

```css
#mdl {
  position: fixed;
  top: 10%;
  left: 25%;
  background: wheat;
  display:none;
}
#mdl_inner {padding:50px;}
#mdl_closeX{padding:5px;text-align:right;cursor:pointer;}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.4/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="mdl">
  <div id="mdl_closeX"> X </div>
  <div id="mdl_inner">My Modal</div>
</div>

<h3>Click on the page body, then press the letter [ s ] </h3>
<p>The [s] binding will work only once. After closing the modal, pressing [s] will not open it again. </p>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. </p>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. </p>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. </p>
```

Here is a modified example that shows how the event handler can be turned off when user is in an input field:

```js
$("body").on('keyup', function(event) {
  if (event.which == 83) {
    $('#mdl').show();
  }
});
$('#mdl_closeX').click(function(){
  $('#mdl').hide();
});

$('input').focus(function(){
  $('body').off('keyup'); //the "s" will only work once
});

$('input').blur(function(){
    $("body").on('keyup', function(event) {
        if (event.which == 83) {
            $('#mdl').show();
            $('body').off('keyup'); //the "s" will only work once
        }
    });
});
```

```css
#mdl {
  position: fixed;
  top: 10%;
  left: 25%;
  background: wheat;
  display:none;
}
#mdl_inner {padding:50px;}
#mdl_closeX{padding:5px;text-align:right;cursor:pointer;}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.4/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="mdl">
  <div id="mdl_closeX"> X </div>
  <div id="mdl_inner">My Modal</div>
</div>

<h3>Click on the page body, then press the letter [ s ] </h3>
<p>The [s] binding will work any time the user is NOT inside an input field. </p>

<div>
    When click in the input field, the "s" will be normalized. Next, click anywhere else on the body and the "s" will once again open the modal.
    <input type="text" />
</div>
```

Here is an example that shows how to assign <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> <kbd>s</kbd> to open the search modal, and not just the letter <kbd>s</kbd>.

*Because there is no keycode for "Ctrl+S" as a pair, we have to track each key  separately. So we use a global variable to track whether the CTRL key has been depressed, and then watch for the "s" only when the Ctrl key is flagged as depressed.*

```js
var ctrldn = false;
$("body").on('keydown', function(event) {
  if (event.which == 17){
    ctrldn = true;
  }
});
$("body").on('keyup', function(event) {
  if (event.which == 17){
    ctrldn = false;
  }
});
$("body").on('keydown', function(event) {
  if (ctrldn && event.which == 83){
    $('#mdl, #olay').show();
    return false;
  }
});





$('#mdl_closeX').click(function(){
  $('#mdl, #olay').hide();
});

$('input').focus(function(){
  ctrldn = false;
  $('body').off('keyup'); //the "s" will only work once
});

$('input').blur(function(){
    $("body").on('keyup', function(event) {
        if (ctrldn && event.which == 83) {
            $('#mdl').show();
            $('body').off('keyup'); //the "s" will only work once
        }
    });
});
```

```css
#olay{
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  background:black;
  opacity: 0.6;
  z-index:9998;
  display:none;
}
#mdl {
  position: fixed;
  top: 10%;
  left: 25%;
  background: wheat;
  z-index:9999;
  display:none;
}
#mdl_inner {padding:50px;}
#mdl_closeX{padding:5px;text-align:right;cursor:pointer;}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.4/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="olay"></div>
<div id="mdl">
  <div id="mdl_closeX"> X </div>
  <div id="mdl_inner">My Modal</div>
</div>

<h3>Click on the page body, then press [ Ctrl ] [ s ] </h3>
<p>[Ctrl] [s] will open the modal no matter where the user is, and will not interfere with the letter [s] by itself. </p>
<p><b>Note that it was necessary to use `return false` to suppress the default action of [Ctrl][s] within the browser</b></p>

<div>
    When click in the input field, the "s" works like the letter "s", and [Ctrl] [s] will open the modal (even in the input field)
    <input type="text" />
</div>
```

#### Update:

I also tweaked the 3rd demo a little to show you how to turn it into a true modal - so there is no need for jQueryUI or any other pre-fab modal. You can just see how they work *under the hood*. Basically, you need an overlay (just a div that covers the entire screen) with a z-index higher than anything else on the page ***except*** the modal dialog. Then you need the modal dialog structure (just an ordinary div with stuff inside it), that is positioned (using z-index) to sit on top of the overlay. Yup, it's that simple.

Comment: Hello. Thanks for the answer. But it should work again once the modal is closed. Not just once per page refresh. I tried with `if($('#search-modal').is(':hidden')){` and it works good, but it targets input and textarea boxes as well. I don't want modal to run when typing in text in fields.

Comment: You can use `.off()` (as demoed in the answer) to turn it off when user is in a field, and turn it back on when user is out of the field. Tell you what: I'll update my answer with an example. *In fact, you might prefer to assign `Ctrl + s` as the search hotkey, rather than just the letter `s`...*

Comment: Thank you. Looking forward to seeing how you'll include it and I'll see to include ctrl+s as you said.

Comment: Just tested and seems like second modal is not opening after closing it once. You must click in input then, get out of input and click s again. is it possible to open it when you close it and open it again? For third example: if you click ctrl + s, and then enter "s" in input it shows modal.

Comment: I'm testing it here on StackOverflow in full-screen mode using chrome. Will clear it now and report results. Thank you for fast answers!

Comment: Just tested again and it works closing and opening it up as long as you don't click on the input field. After clicking on input, you can click just once to open modal and close it. To open it again, you must click the input field and body.

Comment: Ah, I found an error. Try it now. Follow the code carefully - click on the `edited xxx ago` beside the author's name and see the differences in the code.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried a condition like this?

```
if($('#search-modal').is(':visible')){
 //do other things
}
```

Comment: Seems like the problem now is that this targets textarea and input fields as well. Which it shouldn't.